# Distributed lock service implementation in Golang

Tags: go, concurrency, locking

I have multiple E2E tests (written in Java) which share login details, each test during runtime will query the locker API for login details which is running on its own dedicated server.

Below is my implementation of my locker API in Go, it was working for me but wanted to make sure there are no bugs.

```golang
type service struct {
   lockstatus []string // stores test_id denoting which test took the lock
   data       []*LoginDetails // stores login details
   mu         []sync.Mutex // stores locks for "data" slice
}

func (s *service) AcquireLoginDetails(req *Request, resp *Response) error {
   foundLoginDetails := false
   for i := range s.mu {
      // for i, lock := range s.mu <- lock is copied here so will use s.mu[i] directly
      if s.mu[i].TryLock() {
         // skip to next lock if current lock is already taken
         if s.lockstatus[i] != "" {
            s.mu[i].Unlock()
            continue
         } else {
            // use this index to acquire lock for the requested test
            foundLoginDetails = true
            s.lockstatus[i] = req.GetTestID()
            resp.SetUserID(s.LoginDetails[i].UserID)
            resp.SetPassword(s.LoginDetails[i].Password)
         }
         s.mu[i].Unlock()
         if foundLoginDetails { break } // stop searching for further login details
      }
   }
   if !foundLoginDetails {
      return error_explaining_we_failed_to_acquire_lock
   }
   return nil
}

func (s *service) ReleaseLoginDetails(req *Request, resp *Response) error {
   foundLoginDetails := false
   for i, testID := range s.lockstatus {
      if testID == req.GetTestID() {
         s.mu[i].Lock()
         foundLoginDetails = true
         s.lockstatus[i] = ""
         s.mu[i].Unlock()
         break
      }
   }
   if !foundLoginDetails {
      return error_explaining_we_failed_to_release_lock
   }
   return nil
}
```

Comment: Well, first, code reviews are not for SO, so your question is off-topic; please consider using <https://codereview.stackexchange.com/>. Next, «each test during runtime will query the locker service for login details» conveys insufficient amount of information for proper assessment of your implementation. For instance, if `AcquireLoginDetails` is called from multple concurrently executing goroutines, you have multiple data races—over each of the slices,—and if not, then there's no point in using mutexes at all: just have boolean flags.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its off-topic.